# Container built in Kaniko has bad directory permissions, but works when built in Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, permissions, kaniko

I created a Dockerfile to run a simple Vue.js SPA using [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/) as the webserver.

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:fermium-alpine AS builder

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache \
    git && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm set progress=false && \
    npm config set depth 0 && \
    npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache \
    lighttpd \
    curl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ./support/lighttpd/*.conf /etc/lighttpd/

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=1s CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /var/www/localhost/htdocs/

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/lighttpd", "-D", "-f", "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"]
```

(The lighttpd config is modified to redirect not found routes back to the application so that `pushState` navigation can be used, with the addition of a single line: `server.error-handler-404 = "/index.html"`.)

When I build this container directly in Docker Desktop for Windows, it works perfectly, but when I build it using Kaniko (run by GitLab CI in Docker Desktop for Mac), I get the following error when I try to run the container:

```
2020-12-11 05:39:25: (server.c.752) opening errorlog '/var/log/lighttpd/error.log' failed: Permission denied
2020-12-11 05:39:25: (server.c.1485) Opening errorlog failed. Going down.
```

When I compare the containers, I see the following difference:

#### Docker Desktop built

```
/ # ls -la /var/log/lighttpd/
total 8
drwxr-s---    2 lighttpd wheel         4096 Dec 11 04:26 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Dec 11 04:26 ..
```

#### Kaniko built

```
/ # ls -la /var/log/lighttpd/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 11 04:51 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Dec 11 04:51 ..
```

Why does the Kaniko-built container have the wrong permissions on the log directory?